# ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'Cython'

Tags: pandas, module, pip, pycharm, cython

I am trying to install pandas module on PyCharm. When i try to install it it gave me this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'Cython' " (Screen: https://prnt.sc/qafwcy)

So i went on the CMD to try to install the Cython package with this command: py -m pip install Cython , which gave me an other error: "The script, f2py.exe is install in 'C:\xxx.xxxx, which is not a PATH. (Screen: https://prnt.sc/qafvx3)

Does anyone had the same problem and know how to fix it?
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm uses a virtual environment - one separate from your python install on your computer. This is to isolate your development environment from the one you would use on your computer.

Enter your pip commands here instead:

[image: pycharm terminal]

Comment: @tiberhockey please except my answer above if this has worked